# How does magnifyingGlass work for Geo Chart?

Tags: google-visualization

It sounds that magnifying glass feature is very useful for small countries (e.g. Andorra, Liechtenstein, etc.).  However, I never seen any region got magnified in my test. According to the document, the default value is {enable: true, zoomFactor: 5.0}, so it should be enabled by default. Why can't I see the effects? How should I make it work?

BTW: I tried both latest Chrome and Firefox, none of them works.

Comment: the magnifying glass only appears when there are multiple markers in the same area, do you have an example you can share?

Comment: Do you mean it only work for Marker GeoCharts? I would like to use it for Region GeoCharts. Is it possible? Without this feature, it is not possible to show those small countries. :(

Comment: I've only seen it work on markers, there is an example here --> [marker-geocharts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#marker-geocharts) -- hover over the cluttered markers around Rome to see the magnifying glass

Answer (score 0):

The magnifying glass appears  when the user lingers over a cluttered marker.  When the user lingers over a cluttered marker, a magnifiying glass will be opened.

Note: this feature is not supported in browsers that do not support SVG, i.e. Internet Explorer version 8 or earlier.